MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms at Timeout.<anonymous>
It gives the error like this in terminal
MongooseError: The uri parameter to openUri() must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to mongoose.connect() or mongoose.createConnection() is a string.
    at NativeConnection.createClient (F:\Coding\Mern Luminar\MEARN\mern-blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:206:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (F:\Coding\Mern Luminar\MEARN\mern-blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:801:34)
    at Mongoose.connect (F:\Coding\Mern Luminar\MEARN\mern-blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\mongoose.js:404:15)
    at file:///F:/Coding/Mern%20Luminar/MEARN/mern-blog/api/index.js:10:4
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
Server is running on port 3000!
F:\Coding\Mern Luminar\MEARN\mern-blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-natative\collection.js:185
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (F:\Coding\Mern Luminar\MEARN\mern-blog\node_modules\mongoose\e\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)

Node.js v18.17.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

This is the index.js file
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import userRoutes from './routes/user.route.js';
dotenv.config();
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('MongoDb is connected');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
const app = express();
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000!');
});
app.use('/api/user', userRoutes);

This is the .env file
MONGO=mongodb+srv://justinv:justin@7@mern-blog-t.srmbuat.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=mern-blog-t

You need to share your code where you are making the connection.

The error says: The uri parameter to openUri() must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to mongoose.connect() or mongoose.createConnection() is a string.  I doubt anyone can make it more clear. as jQueeny said - please evidence you passed correct connection details to mongoose.

(1) Are you able to connect to MongoDB server using the URI "mongodb+srv://justinv:justin@7@mern-blog-t.srmbuat.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=mern-blog-t" from mongosh or MongoDB Compass? (2) Console.log the value of process.env.MONGO and see what its value is. (3) Also, see How to read environment variables from Node.js

import 'dotenv/config'; then delete import dotenv from 'dotenv'; and dotenv.config(); Make sure .env is in the root directory.

yeah my problem was env was not in root directory .Thank you so much

Increase the timeout limit then it will be resolved.
mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000 });

btw-Luminaril placements indo?
